# MVC webgrid column width?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

Now am working on MVC webgrid. I need to set the column width based on the requirement.

## Grid:

```
 @{ 
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model.TenantList, rowsPerPage: 11, canPage: true, canSort: false);
        @grid.Table(
        headerStyle: "headerStyle",
        tableStyle: "table table-responsive fixed-column fixed-column table-striped table-hover a-grid",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alternateStyle",
        htmlAttributes: new { id = "tenantgrid" },
        columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("Action", style: "labelcolumn cchk",format:@<text><input class="checkbox cchk" id="assignChkBx" name="assignChkBx" value="@item.Person_Code" type="checkbox" onClick="assignChkBx()" /></text>),
        grid.Column("TitleName"),
        grid.Column("FullName",style: "name-width"),
        grid.Column("Employee_Number"),
        grid.Column("Fathername"),
        grid.Column("Address"),
        grid.Column("EMAILID")
        )
    )
    }
```

## Css:

```
.name-width {
        width:500px;
    }
```

problem is the class is called like this

```
<td class="name-width">AMEER ABOOBACKER</td>
```

But its not applying my grid. I cant find the error. friends give me the solution........
 Thanks advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a class for each column as you mentioned.
The style you have for your table has **fixed-column** and most probably that's overriding your custom css. You could remove that class *(and use below instead)* or alternatively you can try adding !important to your css property.
Below should work as expected.

```
    @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table table-hover",
                      columns:
        grid.Columns
        (
                grid.Column("Property1", "Property1", style: "Large"),
                grid.Column("Property2", "Property2", style: "Small")
                grid.Column("Action", format: @<text>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id})
                    | @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
                </text>, style: "action", canSort: false)))

<style type="text/css">
.Large{
    width: 20%;
}

.Small{
    width: 5%;
}
```